# R ClustOfVar: Error when there are 3 identical columns in the data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

When we do variable clustering in R using package `ClustOfVar`, we typically need to cut the clustering tree into groups by specifying parameters `h` (height) or `k`  (the desired number of clusters).

It always works fine when we use `k` (as long as k is less than the number of columns).

But when we use `h` to cutree, if there are 3 or more than 3 identical columns, chances are big that there will be an error.  (Please run the following code some more times if you don't get the error message.)

```
A = sample(LETTERS[1:4],40,replace = TRUE)
B = A
C = A

fit = hclustvar(X.quali = data.frame(A,B,C))
plot(fit)
cutree(fit,h=0.5)

#Error in cutree(fit, h = 0.5) : 
#  the 'height' component of 'tree' is not sorted (increasingly)
```

---

In the following example, we have groups of only 2 identical columns. And it never fails.

```
A = sample(LETTERS[1:4],40,replace = TRUE)
B = A
C = sample(LETTERS[1:2],40,replace = TRUE)
D = C
fit = hclustvar(X.quali = data.frame(A,B,C,D))
plot(fit)
cutree(fit,h=0.5)
```

---

If we add one more identical column to the second example:

```
A = sample(LETTERS[1:4],40,replace = TRUE)
B = A
C = sample(LETTERS[1:2],40,replace = TRUE)
D = C
E = C
fit = hclustvar(X.quali = data.frame(A,B,C,D,E))
plot(fit)
cutree(fit,h=0.5)
#Error in cutree(fit, h = 0.5) : 
#  the 'height' component of 'tree' is not sorted (increasingly)
```

Again it fails from time to time.

I think cutting the clustering tree by `h` is more practical and convenient cause it's more consistent and sense-making.

Is there any workaround that could make it work? Or is there any more stable packages in R that can do variable clustering? Thanks.

Comment: First, are you really trying to do variable clustering on only 3 variables ? Then you can use `K` to specify the number of groups. You can determine the number of group graphically with `plot(fit,type="index")`, which show the aggregation levels plot. Try to plot the tree without cuting it may be height didn't go much higher than the `h` you specify

Comment: @ChristopheD. No, I'm not clustering on 3 variables. I'm just trying to figure out the root causes of the error message. I do need `h` to cluster my big data.

Comment: Ok wanted to be sure. Have you tried to check the tree height range without cutting it ?